# nested functions in gcc using -std=c99

Tags: c, gcc

From what I am reading the below code is invalid c99, however I seem to be able to compile it using gcc -std=c99 which, to my knowledge should disable the GNU extension that allows for embedded functions. I cannot seem to figure out why this is the case.

```
int main() {
    int e() {
        printf("testing");
        return 0;
    };

    e();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get warnings on non-conformant code you need to use the `-pedantic` flag as well, then you will see the following (*[see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba2a859ad99ef8d2)*):

```
warning: ISO C forbids nested functions [-Wpedantic]
 int e() {
 ^
```

To turn this into an error you can use `-Werror` to turn warnings into errors or `-pedantic-errors`.

From the gcc docs on [standards support](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html):

> to obtain all the diagnostics required by the standard, you should also specify -pedantic (or -pedantic-errors if you want them to be errors rather than warnings)

Comment: Thanks :), I should have read the man page more carefully. It turns out that gcc only complains by default if you use an extension which conflicts with the standard specified rather than one which just extends it :S.